# Why has this blockchain transaction not confirmed?

Tags: blockchain, transaction-fees, zero-confirmation

ea5ee0a3734356a71b2b39deafb656715bad42fb297497f7f694d4a7a0f6335c

Is due to the fee being low 0.0001? or something else?

Comment: the same problem here,and you are right the problem not due to the fee . still not have the notification or and news from BLockchain admin. why? :( when is my transactions confirmed

Comment: Hi @user42641: If you want to get individual help, it would probably be best if you create a new question and provide your transaction ID, so that people can give informed replies.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a (currently) unconfirmed input: https://blockchain.info/tx-index/106830375/1

There is also a warning on this input (previous output) that it is a double spend, probably due to the ongoing malleability attack.

```
Warning! this transaction is a double spend. You should be extremely careful when trusting any transactions to/from this sender
```

[image]

Comment: what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

It just takes a little bit longer than you are expecting. Wait a little longer. As you can see on blockchain.info your transaction is being considered "high priority" so I would say the wait time is not due to your transaction fee.

Estimated Confirmation Time:    *Very Soon (High Priority)*

https://blockchain.info/tx/ea5ee0a3734356a71b2b39deafb656715bad42fb297497f7f694d4a7a0f6335c

Comment: It happens, can be stressful at times. No need to worry.

Comment: Used blockchain for many years and this is the longest I've had to wait. I guess I just got lucky before

Comment: What else could it be due to?

Comment: StephenM347♦ seems to have found the cause.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get my money back??

Comment: At this point I don't think there's much you can do besides wait. Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed to my knowledge. If I understand correctly I think malleability attacks just slow down transactions but don't actually stop them from completing. Basically an annoyance.

Comment: Ok slow is bad but I can live with it, how long are we talking for this kind of thing resolve? or is it the proverbial 'piece of string'

Comment: Pretty sure it's a guessing game at this point. Maybe someone else has more insight?